how to force ansible to ignore $HOME/.ssh
When I verbosely launch ansible with ansible-playbook -vvvv -i inventory.yml  directories.yml in middle of output I can see:
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/freq/.ssh/known_hosts"$
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/freq/.ssh/known_hosts:52$
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 2.2.2.1$
debug1: Host \'2.2.2.1\' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.$

How do I set ansible's config file(s) to make ansible to ignore $HOME/.ssh/ and take ssh's config and known_hosts from location of my choice?

This should be doable by overriding the underlying SSH options.
Add something like this in your ansible.cfg file:
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -F ~/.ssh/custom_ssh_config

man ssh:

       -F configfile
               Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file.  If a configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) will  be
               ignored.  The default for the per-user configuration file is ~/.ssh/config.  If set to “none”, no configuration files will be read.

Use /etc/ssh/ssh_config as a template and add your own customizations.
Basically you'll have to uncomment a few lines at least like IdentityFile or UserKnownHostsFile. Untested but you get the idea. I suggest to test the -F option in SSH first. When you've got the SSH config right, adapt your Ansible config file.
